# How do I find all real pairs of $a,b$ such that $\frac {80+b}{10a+b}$ is an integer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How do I find all real pairs of a,b such that $\dfrac {80+b}{10a+b}$ is an integer?

I tried using the Euclidean algorithm and I ran it with $80+b$ and $10a+b$ once assuming $80+b>10a+b$ but then I didn't know what to do.

I came up with this problem when I was trying to solve a crossword which needed to use lots of trial and error but I wanted a more "efficient" method so I translated the crossword into a number theory question, which I now am wanting to solve.

[image]

While solving the problem, when I encountered an issue, I would try and approach it mathematically, due to the crossword presumably expecting translating crosswords into mathematical statements. For the most part I did not encounter many problems, it was mostly just case work with maybe some algebra manipulations and basic formulae, however it is 5 across and 4 down that has stumped me.

what it says for the information is that $4$ down is a proper factor of $5$ across (I already have filled in numbers for the other boxes). So that is how I got my question. Now to be clear, I frankly do not care about the solution to the crossword - rather I would like to know how to solve the problem mentioned, the crossword is more of how the question came to be.

Comment: You asked basically the same question, except without the clarification that $a$ and $b$ are real and your attempt, just about an hour ago at [How do I find all pairs of (a.b) such that (80+b)/(10a+b) is an integer?](/q/4519140/602049). Although it was closed, instead of deleting it & reposting your question, you should have instead updated your original post and tried to get it reopened.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to ask about $(80a+b)/(10a+b)$? [in the question discussion at one point it seems you mean $80a+b$ not $80+b$ in the numerator]

Comment: @bobjeff123 Also, since the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) "... is an efficient method for computing the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) (GCD) of two integers (numbers)", since you mentioned trying to use it, are you sure that $a$ and $b$ are meant to be real numbers?

Comment: @coffeemath thank you I edited the mistake

Comment: Have you seen the advice on [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Im not sure if my approach was right but yes its real numbers

Comment: If you don't have any idea how to start, see what you can add to the question body [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @TobyMak what are some things I could improve on for this post? Thanks

Comment: @bobjeff123 Rather than working on the Euclidean algorithm as it might get messy with two variables, where does this problem come from? This will form the context of the question which makes it easier for us to answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138800/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-bobjeff123).

Comment: See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%2880%2Bb%29%2F%2810a%2Bb%29%3Dn%2C+solve+for+a

Comment: Given your number crossword intention, it would seem a and b are digits, that is integers from 0 to 9, not simply real numbers.

Comment: @coffeemath if you read my post, I stated that I do not wish to solve the crossword, rather the question stated. The crossword was just inspiration for the question.

Comment: @bobjeff123 If you want real a,b solutions you can just set your fractional expression to equal any specific integer, call that integer $u.$ Then for any real $a$ there is exactly one $b$ which makes your expression equal to the integer $u.$ The algebra to do that involves little more than "cross multiplying", and gives $b=10(8-au)/(u-1).$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP should have edited the earlier version of this question instead of posting anew.

Comment: @jyrkilahtonen wait what is wrong with deleting the old question and posting anew?

Comment: On this site everything that can be deleted can also be undeleted. Users with enough rep can still see it. The site norms are heavily against such orphaned (or hit-and-run) questions. For example, if you leave too many of them (particularly negatively voted ones) you will be put under a post ban. If that happens, you are not allowed to post again until the positive contributions outweigh the negative ones. To accomplish that you need to improve your badly received posts. Another factor, is that the site norms are also against duplicated questions, for much the same reasons.

Comment: (cont'd) This comment space is too small, and I don't remember all of it. Check out the meta, and search for post bans to get all the details and all the reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you the following approach.

Let $k≠1$ be an integer, such that

\begin{aligned}\frac {80+b}{10a+b}=k&\implies 10ak+bk=b+80\\
&\implies b(k-1)=80-10ak\\
&\implies b=\frac {80-10ak}{k-1}\end{aligned}

We have $2$ possible cases:

If $k=1$, then $a=8, b\in\mathbb R$.

If $k≠1$, then

$$a\in\mathbb R, \, \,\, b=\frac {80-10ak}{k-1}$$

where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yes, the OP is trying to add context to their question and they have made some improvements, but the question doesn't meet the quality standards of this site just yet.

Comment: For reference see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards

Comment: So please don't answer the question until it has enough context: "If you encounter a low-quality question, don't answer it immediately. Instead, direct the user to the meta post How to Ask a Good Question. Help them to understand what the standards are on this site, and consider offering advice on how they might improve their question. Make it clear that there are expectations for participation in this community, but always remain polite."

Comment: @TobyMak Oh, thank you for points. I edited the OP's question for some improvements

Comment: (edited) Don't edit their post to change the content, but yeah formatting edits are perfectly fine.